# How can I make only the character clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, image, click

I'm trying to make a game, where if you click on a character he says something to you. Currently, I'm using image files. However, the images are always in a rectangle, so if you click on the space under a character's arm, he'll do something.[image: This is what I'm talking about.]

I don't want that to happen, so what do I have to do?

Comment: Are image maps an option?

Comment: I assume you're using JavaScript? If so, you should add that to the tags.

Comment: what do you mean by "image maps?"

Comment: It would be much easier to include separate images.